# A phrase where you make an effort and succeed

Tags: idioms

Let's say a sports team puts in a lot of effort and as a result perform very well. You could say they have "-blank-ed themselves" as praise.
I feel like the word is on the tip of my tongue but I can't think of it.

Comment: _the effort they put in really [paid off](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pay+off)_

Comment: It is interesting to me that my search for "outdone themselves" turned up results on ESPN while "acquitted themselves" turned up results on BBC sport. I wouldn't go so far as to claim this question ought to be tagged "British English" but there definitely seems to be a preference.

Answer (score 6):

Someone who does exceptionally well, particularly compared to their past performance can be said to have "[outdone themselves](https://www.quora.com/What-does-Youve-outdone-yourself-this-time-mean)"

> We knew the importance and significance of this tournament, and credit must go to each and every individual. And also to all the management and backroom staff. They've all outdone themselves."

Source: [ESPN](http://www.espn.com/cricket/story/_/id/22908824/one-best-s-come-together-side-jason-holder)

Answer (score 2):

They have [**excelled**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/excelled) (themselves):

> transitive verb
>
> : to be superior to : surpass in accomplishment or achievement
>
> intransitive verb
>
> : to be distinguishable by superiority : surpass others · *excel* in sports · *excelled* at lipreading

Comment: Please attribute correctly to comply with ELU guidelines **and copyright laws**.

Answer (score 2):

Ah! I just thought of it, *acquit*.
“They *acquitted* themselves well.”

*edit*

> Stephen Robinson's side acquitted themselves well against the Scottish
>   champions in November's League Cup final

Source: [BBC Sport](https://www.bbc.com/sport/football/44126935)

Merriam Webster: [To Acquit Oneself](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acquit%20oneself)

Comment: Look more closely, folks.   This is not a “thank you answer”; the OP is *not* posting “thank you” *as* an answer.   This is an answer, PERIOD.   Then, parenthetically, the author thanks the people who participated; yes, that part should be edited out.   But this ***is*** an answer, and it should not be deleted.

Comment: You need to add a linked and attributed supporting reference showing this sense of 'acquit', even though the answer is correct. ELU regulations.

Answer (score 0):

**be a howling success**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/success)

> To be extremely or triumphantly successful.